# solving 2 subscripts optimisation transportation probs using R

Tags: r, optimization

Can someone please guide on how to solve the below. I am not looking for the answer but a start to solving such problems in R. I have looked at packages like lsolve and lsolveapi but all the examples are with just one subscript

Minimize
132x11 + 12x12 + 97x21 + 103x22

subject to
constraint1 :  x11+ x12 + x21 ≤ 135
constraint2 :  x11 + x21 + x22   ≤ 56

xij≥ 0, all i, j

please help and recommend suitable R packages for the same for such large sclae problems

Comment: The name of the variables is irrelevant: if the double indices trouble you, you can always rename your variables from `x11`, `x12`, `x21`, `x22` to `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, `y4`. All the linear programming packages (`lpSolve`, etc.) can solve this small problem (4 variables do not make the problem "large scale").

Comment: Vincent : This is a customer and supplier problem: x11 is used to represent customer 1 and supplier1 and similary x12 represents customer1 and supplier2...... please note i have just copied just 2-3 lines  and 4 variables of the actual problem.... Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Per comments, it looks as though your probelm as written is a near-perfect match to the example given in the `lp()` function of `lpSolve`.  See if this works:

```
library(lpSolve)
f.obj <- c(132, 12, 97, 103)
f.con <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), ncol = 4, byrow = T)
f.dir <- c(">=", ">=")
f.rhs <- c(135, 56)
lp ("min", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)
#Success: the objective function is 6380 
lp ("min", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)$solution
#0 79 56  0
```

Thus a full answer to your question would be to install package `sos`, then use `findFn("solve")` or something of that nature.  In fact, if you type `findFn("transportation")` you will see several packages that specifically solve linear programs (if you couldn't get what you need from something in base `R` such as `?solve`.

Comment: Jack thanks for the link and giving a start....i will explore findFn("transportation") option....   f.con <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), ncol = 4, byrow = T) i am not quite sure if it is matching the constraint requirement.